# adding/using ak4554 codec chip to raspbian-Jessie (Raspberry pi)

Tags: python, audio, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, hardware-interface

I am using python3 as my application language on the PI.

My specific problem is, I need to interface with the [AK4554VT chipset][1] for audio support on a raspberry pi 3, running raspbian-jessie.

I have found a reference (below) that appears to be drivers included in the kernel, but I have no idea how to access them in order to communicate with the external hardware.

My end goal is to:

1) load the drivers at boot-time (preferred) or optionally through a python routine in application space
2) setup both the input and output concurrently to run with pygame controls.

Reference: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ak4554

I will likely require some special tweaks for the following pinout

```
MCLK = pin 32
LRCK = pin 36
SDTO = Pin 38
SDTI = pin 40
SCLK = Pin 18
```

being a noob myself, and for prosperity of anyone else who would follow, step by step is greatly appreciated.